# Define a type in typescript with conditional properties / limits

Tags: typescript, types

I'm new to typescript and have learned how to define a custom type like:

> type T = {a:number, b:any}

Is it possible to define a type in TypeScript for the set of all strings with length larger than 2 using the type constructors defined in class?

or maybe define a type for the set of all numbers larger than 0?

Comment: no, you could only declare a variable with either `any` or other data types without any logical limitations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you can't impose such arbitrary constraint at compile time, you can create types that force the user to call a functions that performs these validations and then rely on these invariants in your code using branded type

```
type PositiveNumber =  number & { positive: true}
type StringOfMinLength<T extends number> =  string & { minLegth: T}

type T = {a:PositiveNumber, b:StringOfMinLength<3> }

function isPositiveNumber(value: number): value is PositiveNumber {
    if( value < 0 ) return false
    return  true;
}
function asPositiveNumber(value: number) {
    if( !isPositiveNumber(value) ) throw new Error("Not ok")
    return value; // type guard above, value will now be a PositiveNumber 
}

function isStringOfMinLength<T extends number>(value: string, length: T): value is StringOfMinLength<T> {
    if( value.length < length ) return false;
    return true;
}

function asStringOfMinLength<T extends number>(value: string, length: T): StringOfMinLength<T> {
    if(!isStringOfMinLength(value, length) ) throw new Error("Not ok")
    return value; // type guard above, value will now be a PositiveNumber 
}

type MyData = {a:PositiveNumber, b:StringOfMinLength<3>}
let myObj: MyData = {
    a: asPositiveNumber(0),
    b: asStringOfMinLength("Test", 3),
}

Math.sqrt(myObj.a) // a will be greater then 0
myObj.b[2] // index will exist, length greater then 3

let myNotOkObject: MyData = {
    a: -1, // will be a compile error, the checking function is not called
    b: "Test" // this will also be an error event though it satisfies the constraint since we don't call the appropriate function
}

// we can also use the type guard version instead (is*) of the assertion version (as*)
let a = 10;
let b = "Test"
if(isPositiveNumber(a) && isStringOfMinLength(b, 3))
{
    let myOtherObj: MyData = { a, b } // a and b are PositiveNumber and respectively StringOfMinLength<3>
} else {
    // handle case when they are not what was expected
}
```

You can use a branded type anywhere the base type is required (ex `Math.sqrt(myObj.a)`) but you can't assign the base type directly to a field of the branded type. Whether this has value in real code is up to you and your use case.

This [article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/01/15/typescript-flexible-nominal-typing/) has a bit more of a discussion on branded types.

**Edit**

Added a type guard version of the branded type creation functions, that way you can check if an invariant is true and handle the false case on your own instead of having an error thrown. 10x to @AluanHaddad for the idea.

Comment: Why not use a type guard instead of throwing? That way you don't have to use type assertions and you don't have to assign the result. Of course your approach is perfectly valid.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I didn't think of type guards at the time, but you are right a type guard version of the functions would be very useful. But both versions would be needed, the throw version and the type guard version, in some cases it would be easier to just asset the value is valid, and throw an error otherwise, while in others a guard would be better. I will add a type guard version shortly. 10x for the idea :-)

Comment: good point. Now that you mention it, you could call the type guard function from the throwing validator. That should infer the result type of the validator from the type guard because the false branch would throw. Some nice code-reuse there :) anyway +1

Comment: @AluanHaddad yup, that was the way I was going to do it, makes the validator version look better too, no assertion :) 10x again

Comment: Where in your example are these "types that force the user to call a functions that performs these validations"?