# Is it possible to define custom type rules for primitive types?

Tags: typescript

This may be a silly question, but is it possible to achieve something like the following in TypeScript?

```
let test: AllCapsString = "this is a string"; // fails type checking
let test: AllCapsString = "THIS IS A STRING"; // passes type checking
```

If so, how would one define the type or interface for `AllCapsString`?

Comment: I researched this a couple months ago to prevent strings from containing a "-" but I didn't find anything so I think you'll find the answer to be "no".

Comment: This is the closest thing I have come up with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49673001/define-a-type-in-typescript-with-conditional-properties-limits/49673307#49673307