# Typescript interface expect one number props to be less than another number prop

Tags: typescript, types, interface, numbers

Is it possible to make a TypeScript interface accept a `number` prop that's value is always supposed to be less than another `number` prop in the interface?

For example, if I had a `numberOfFiles` prop and a `currentFileIndex` prop and I always expect the `currentFileIndex` prop to be less than `numberOfFiles`. Could I define that in my interface.

Something along the lines like this:

```
interface IProps {
  numberOfFiles: number;
  currentFileIndex: number<less than numberOfFiles>;
}
```

It's not the end of the world if it's not possible but it would be great to know whether or not it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this directly, typescript has no way to model such a constraint.

You could however force all users of this interface to perform a the check early by using branded types similarly to what is presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49673001/define-a-type-in-typescript-with-conditional-properties-limits/49673307#49673307)

```
interface IProps {
    numberOfFiles: number;
    currentFileIndex: number & { mustBeLessThenNumberOfFiles: true };
}

type Omit<T, TKeys extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, TKeys>>
function createProps(p: Omit<IProps, 'currentFileIndex'> & {
    currentFileIndex: number 
}) {
    if(p.currentFileIndex > p.numberOfFiles) throw "Error!";
    return p as IProps;
}

//ok
createProps({
    numberOfFiles: 10,
    currentFileIndex: 5
});

// compiles but with runtime error when props are created
createProps({
    numberOfFiles: 10,
    currentFileIndex: 15
});

// error
let p : IProps = {
    numberOfFiles: 10,
    currentFileIndex: 5 // error we did not make sure with a check 
}
```

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle always fun to mush the type sistem :)