# Class implements interface in typescirpt

Tags: typescript

I was wondering why does not typescript compiler throw error on code below:

```
interface Greetings {
    greeting: string;
}

class Human implements Greetings {
    greeting: string = "Why hello there";
}

class Lion implements Greetings {
    greeting: string = "Roar";
}

class Lemon {
    greeting: string = "I'M A LEMON";
}

class LivingSpecies {
    private species: Greetings;

    public greet() {
        console.log(this.species.greeting)
    }

    constructor(species: Greetings) {
        this.species = species;
    }
}

const species1 = new LivingSpecies(new Human())
species1.greet(); // "Why hello there"

const species2 = new LivingSpecies(new Lion())
species2.greet(); // "Roar"

const species3 = new LivingSpecies(new Lemon()) // Why compiler does not complain here?
species3.greet(); // "I'M A LEMON" <--- Why?
```

For the first two cases it works as intended, both classes implement `Greetings` interface, and `LivingSpecies` constructor requires class that implements it. But `Lemon` class "passes" the constructor parameter as if it implements `Greetings` interface. Could you explain this? Thank you.

Comment: I'm assuming you expect this because you're used to languages which use nominal subtyping - i.e T is assignable to U if and only if T explicitly extends U. In typescript you have structural subtyping - i.e T is assingable to U if U's properties are a subset of T's. This means that two objects with the same properties are considered the same type. You can read more here on how this works in TS here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

Comment: @mbdavis so, structural subtyping is like relying on signature and not on the type name?

Comment: exactly! as to the why - does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55180304/why-does-typescript-allow-for-subtyping

Comment: Well, your comment already answered my question xd. Thank you. And yes, marked as duplicate.